Two screens in potrait mode cannot display an application using all available screen space
I have two screens in portrait mode connected to a RPi 4b. Buth screens are the same brand and type, I use both screens in 2560x1440. One screen is the top screen, the other screen obviously the bottom screen. This gives me a total screen width of 1440 and a screen height of 5120 pixels.
On these combined screens I would like to display a webbrowser in full screen mode that shows a pretty long list of items.
But some some reason I get weird behaviour when I try to vertically increase the length of the webbrowser that I placed on the top of the upper screen. At about 2/3 of the lower screen I cannot increase the size of the window. Some applications just crash (Chromium) and other applications just do not allow you to increase the size anymore (Firefox). When I do the same thing with a file explorer or terminal, the window just get black until I decrease the size of that window under that magical 2/3 of the buttom screen.
I am running a plain Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit, bookworm. I only replaced the default window manager  for KDE and also switched from and to X11 / Wayland without any difference..
I cannot pinpoint the exact length of the window when it starts to act weird, various tools like xwininfo and xdotool did not provide me much usefull information.
Has somebody any idea in what area to look? framebuffer size? Hardware limitations? parameter tweaks?
Any help is welcome.

Sometimes scaling settings can interfere with how windows are displayed. scaling should be set to 100% for both displays.  In KDE, go to System Settings > Display and Monitor to check the arrangement and resolution.
